# Transcript long audio with google speech to text

Tags: php, speech-to-text, flac, google-api-go-client

I need to translate a video to text with google speech to text 
I use google speech to text for lon audio, my video's duration is more than 1 minute and maximum can be 10min, but always i have this error that i can't understand

> thrown in /home/outyng2015/public_html/phone_call/vendor/google/gax/src/ApiException.php on line 139
>   [17-Mar-2020 22:34:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\ApiCore\ApiException: {
>       "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
>       "code": 3,
>       "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
>       "details": []
>   }

Comment: Would be very useful, if you want help, to see some code. Please remember we are not clairvoyant

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)